# How to configure magit to make magit-status result the same as 'git status -s'

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I want using magit to show the changes not only the context of files, but also its attributes like file-create-time.

Some file's create time changed, and when try to merge, magit notify that something modified and need to commit first. But there has nothing changed was shown in magit-status. And by run 'git status -s', found one file's create time updated.

Comment: `git status -s` shows a short status message. Are you sure you want to have that as a configuration?

Comment: i'm sure i have made a mistake. I want magit to show the files which create-time changed but file content not changed.

Comment: Can git even store file timestamps?  I would guess it can't (https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/preserving-file-timestamps-with-git-and-mercurial-781386524.html).  This smells like an XY problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I don't know this. I use emacs and magit, git in win10. Regarding this question, maybe some detail information i have lost. Actually, the actions i have done for the file was: 1. pull from remote repo, 2. checkout a new branch 3. view this file in emacs and kill, 4. try to merge from other branch, but fail.

Comment: The problem might be a mismatch of line-endings, as in https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/2401

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your reply.
The tracked file is a '.slx' file, which is a binary file.
This issue can be reproduced when the '.slx' file has been opened by another program(Matlab).
'magit-status' show nothing, but command 'git status' shown the '.slx' file changed. But in fact, nothing changed and only a program has opened this file.